# E-step in EM algorithm with non trivial latent variables

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, inference, expectation-maximization, bayesian-network

I am trying to derive the E-step for an EM algorithm for this model:
[image]

The interesting fact is that there are two sets of latent variables: $z$ and $y$. The E-step involve a derivation of the posterior on the latent variables given the fixed parameters ($\mu$).

During the derivation of the probabilities of the $y$'s I marginalize over $z$ given $\tau$. I wonder: if before this computation I already have computed the $\mu$ for $z$, can I use these computed probabilities instead of marginalizing over $\tau$?

Here is the current result of my derivations:
$$
\mu(z) \propto p(z|\tau)\sum_\mathbf{y}\prod_j^M p(x_j|\phi,y_j) p(y_j|\theta,z)\\
\mu(y_j) \propto \sum_z p(x_j|\phi)p(y_j|\theta,z)p(z|\tau)
$$

So the question can be rephrased as: in the derivation of $\mu(y_j)$, can
I replace $p(z|\tau)$ with $\mu(z)$ ?

Comment: Sure, here I am focusing on the expectation step. My point is related to the fact that the expectations over $z$ and $x$ are done in sequence. For this reason, If I have already computed the expectation over $z$, then, can I use these values, which are probability values, in the formula of the expectation on $x$?

Comment: just added the formulas :)

Comment: As a general reading, I would suggest [this paper by Meng and Van Dyk](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9868.00082/abstract) that covers conditional EM, which could help in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the fomulas: are you missing a $z$ in $p(y_j|\theta)$ in both formulas? The generic answer to the question is no, you cannot. However, I have difficulties to see why you need the marginals on both $y$ and $z$ when you could use the expectation decomposition above and hence one conditional plus one marginal.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, I indeed forgot $z$ in $p(y_j|\theta)$. The marginalization is the only way I could think of in order to remove the other latent variable. I am having some troubles understanding your expectation decomposition. The E-step is usually the less problematic of the two, so I didn't use expectations but just used basic probability properties (Bayes etc..) in order to get the $\mu$.

Answer (score 2):

When solving the E step in EM, you have to compute
$$Q(\theta,\theta')=\mathbb{E}_\theta[\log L(\theta'|x,Y,Z) | X]$$
which can be decomposed as
$$\mathbb{E}_\theta[\mathbb{E}_\theta[\{\log L(\theta'|x,Y,Z)|X,Z\} | X]$$
and as
$$\mathbb{E}_\theta[\mathbb{E}_\theta[\{\log L(\theta'|x,Y,Z)|X,Y\} | X]$$
where $L(\theta'|x,y,z)$ denotes the complete likelihood,
meaning that the inner integral is for the conditional distribution of the latent given the other latent and the outer one is for the marginal distribution of the other latent.

Since in your case this complete likelihood write as
$$L(\theta|x,y,z)=p(z|\tau)\prod_j^M p(x_j|\phi,y_j) p(y_j|\zeta,z)$$
you get that
$$\log L(\theta|x,y,z)=\log p(z|\tau)+\sum_j^M \{\log p(x_j|\phi,y_j) +\log p(y_j|\zeta,z)\}$$
and hence
$$Q(\theta,\theta')=\mathbb{E}_\theta\left[\mathbb{E}_\theta\left[
\log p(z|\tau')+\sum_j^M \{\log p(x_j|\phi',y_j) +\log p(y_j|\zeta',z)\}\Big|Z,x\right]\Big|x\right]\\=\mathbb{E}_\theta\left[\log p(z|\tau')|x\right]+\sum_j^M\mathbb{E}_\theta\left[\mathbb{E}_\theta\left[\log p(x_j|\phi',y_j) +\log p(y_j|\zeta',z)\}\Big|Z,x\right]\Big|x\right]$$
where the first expectation only depends on the marginal of $Z$ given $X=x$.